# If admin blocks a user then session of that current user should be expired in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session

Is there any way to implement this.

If admin blocks a user then session of that current user should be expired in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a custom membership provider which provides this functionality. This is as far as I know the only way, other than hacking into .NET and remove their serverside cookie. But that wouldn't be recommended.

The ASP.NET Membership is there to implement this. More info on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx

Comment: `serverside cookie` ? when was this born ?

Comment: @this.__courious_geek: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx Session state, the part of the session at the server side :)